# adding horizontal "separating" lines in a single boxplot in Base R plotting

Tags: r, boxplot

I need to add a "separating" line in Base R boxplot to separate difference groups. In the example below, I want to separate groups A and B (each having 2 levels) using a horizontal line (in red). R codes for reproducible results:

```
dat = data.frame(A1 = rnorm(1000, 0, 1), A2 = rnorm(1000, 1, 2),
                 B1 = rnorm(1000, 0.5, 0.5), B2 = rnorm(1000, 1.5, 1.5))
boxplot(dat, horizontal = T, outline=F)
```

[image]

Is there an easy way to do in Base R?

Also, is there an easy way to color the y-axis labels? I want to have A1 and B1 shown as red, and A2 and B2 shown as blue in the axis.

Thanks!

Comment: add `abline(h = 2.5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `abline`. To get the right position take the mean of the `axTicks` of the y-axis.

To get the colored labels, first omit `yaxt` and rebuild `axis` ticks and `mtext`, also using `axTicks`.

```
b <- boxplot(dat, horizontal=T, outline=F, yaxt="n")
ats <- axTicks(2)
axis(2, labels=F)
mtext(b$names, 2, 1, col=c(2, 4), at=ats)
abline(h=mean(ats), lwd=2, col=2)
```

[image]

If you want axis tick label colors corresponding to the labels, use `segments` instead.

```
b <- boxplot(dat, horizontal=T, outline=F, yaxt="n")
ats <- axTicks(2)
abline(h=mean(ats), lwd=2, col=2)
pu <- par()$usr
Map(function(x, y) segments(pu[1] - .2, x, pu[1], x, xpd=T, col=y), ats, c(2, 4))
mtext(b$names, 2, 1, col=c(2, 4), at=ats)
```

[image]

**Edit:** To adjust the space a little more use `at=`option in `boxplot` and leave out the middle `axTicks`.

```
b <- boxplot(dat, horizontal=T, outline=F, yaxt="n", at=c(1, 2, 4, 5))
ats <- axTicks(2)[-3]
abline(h=mean(ats), lwd=2, col=2)
pu <- par()$usr
Map(function(x, y) segments(pu[1] - .2, x, pu[1], x, xpd=T, col=y), ats, c(2, 4))
mtext(b$names, 2, 1, col=c(2, 4), at=ats)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt help! This is very useful :)